# Does order matter while injecting properties in ProxyFactoryBean

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-3

I am trying to inject the aspects in a service. For this service I am creating a proxied object using classic way.

I have written a bean- baseProxy of type (ProxyFactoryBean) which contains a list of all the required advices.

```
    <bean id="baseProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>methodInvocationAdvice</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am creating a proxy for the service like this :

```
<bean id="singproxy" parent="baseProxy">
    <property name="target" ref="singtarget" />
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.spring.learning.SingingService"></property>
</bean>
```

Which doesn't work but when I revert these two properties and write like this :

```
<bean id="singproxy" parent="baseProxy">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.spring.learning.SingingService"></property>
    <property name="target" ref="singtarget" />
</bean>
```

To my surprise it works fine. In spring does it matter on the order for bean ?  Or its a special case with ProxyFactoryBean? 
I tried with Spring 3.0 I am not sure same behavior exists with previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `target` and `targetClass`, It's one or the other, but not both. Here's the relevant source (from org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport), a parent class of `ProxyFactoryBean`:

```
public void setTarget(Object target) {
    setTargetSource(new SingletonTargetSource(target));
}

public void setTargetSource(TargetSource targetSource) {
    this.targetSource = (targetSource != null ? targetSource : EMPTY_TARGET_SOURCE);
}


public void setTargetClass(Class targetClass) {
    this.targetSource = EmptyTargetSource.forClass(targetClass);
}
```

As you can see, both `setTarget()` and `setTargetClass()` write to the same field, so the last assignment wins.

Comment: If its this way then why giving only target solves purpose but giving only targetClass doesn't?

Comment: @java_enthu yeah, it seems like you changed your comment and my answer was to the original comment :-)

Comment: Anyway, it seems like setTarget() is what you need, so get rid of setTargetClass().